# Generate graph with vertices equal to elements of std::next_permutation, with edges between pairwise adjacent permutations

Tags: c++, algorithm, permutation

Consider the code snippet:

```
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <stdio.h>
int main(){
     int szvec = 4;
     std::vector<int> vecint(szvec);
     for (size_t i = 0, szi = szvec; i < szi; i++){
         vecint[i] = i;
     }
     do{
         for (size_t i = 0, szi = vecint.size(); i < szi; i++){
             printf("%d\t", vecint[i]);
         }
         printf("\n");
     } while (std::next_permutation(vecint.begin(), vecint.end()));
}
```

The output of this is the set of 4! different permutations.:

```
0       1       2       3   (Permutation 1)
0       1       3       2   (Permutation 2)
0       2       1       3
0       2       3       1
0       3       1       2
0       3       2       1
1       0       2       3
1       0       3       2
1       2       0       3
1       2       3       0
1       3       0       2
1       3       2       0
2       0       1       3
2       0       3       1
2       1       0       3   (Permutation 15)
2       1       3       0
2       3       0       1
2       3       1       0
3       0       1       2
3       0       2       1
3       1       0       2
3       1       2       0
3       2       0       1   (Permutation 23)
3       2       1       0   (Permutation 24)
```

I am interested in constructing an undirected graph with 24 nodes, (each node represents one permutation), with an edge connecting `i` and `j` if these permutations differ from each other in exactly one contiguous pair of elements. For instance, Permutation 1 and Permutation 2 will be connected since they differ in the pairwise exchange *over contiguous* indices. Permutation 1 and Permutation 15 will NOT be connected since even though they differ in pairwise exchange of elements, this exchange is not over contiguous indices. Permutation 23 and Permutation 24 will be connected.

The only way I can think of now of how to do this is to select each pair of permutations and evaluate explicitly whether they should be connected. Is there a more efficient way of doing this analytically? What I mean by analytical here is that given a particular node `i`, can we efficiently enumerate all other permutations it will be connected to? Note that `szvec` can be an arbitrary integer, not only `4`.

---

ETA: With `szvec = 3`, we have six permutations:

```
0   1   2   (Permutation 1)
0   2   1   (Permutation 2)
1   0   2   (Permutation 3)
1   2   0   (Permutation 4)
2   0   1   (Permutation 5)
2   1   0   (Permutation 6)
```

and the graph looks so:

```
 ___________________
|                   |
5 - 6 - 4 - 3 - 1 - 2
```

Comment: As far as I can tell, the `next_permutation` only seems relevant to the demo you've created. Your actual question is just "how to enumerate all adjacent pairwise permutations given a starting permutation", correct?

Comment: @cigien given a starting permutation explicitly, say as a vector, then, it is AFAIK, an O(n) operations to enumerate its pairwise adjacent exchanges. The need for std::next_permutation is that permutation with node `i` is the `i`th enumerated output of std::next_permutation. Does that make sense? In any case, even if we neglected std::next_permutation completely, I want to construct a graph as described in the OP, where each node represents a permutation and adjacent nodes to this represent the adjacent pairwise exchanged permutations.

Comment: correct me if I'm wrong, but isn't each permutation exactly connected to only the next permutation?

Comment: @lajoo No. Permutation 1 is connected to 2 and also Permutaton 7, which is 1 0 2 3

Comment: Take a permutation, swap adjacent elements. Repeat for each pair of adjacent elements.

Comment: it sounds like each would have `szvec-1` neighbors and it's not a fully connected graph, one with islands,

Comment: @n.1.8e9-where's-my-sharem. I suppose that could work, but that seems quite brute-forceish. I don't think this is any more efficient that the method I had suggested in the OP, which is to consider 24 choose 2 pairs of permutations and explicitly check if they are connected.

Comment: I've edited the title to be a bit clearer, but I think it would be helpful if you added an example with just `szvec` of 3, but *also* the resulting graph.

Comment: @Swift-FridayPie Indeed. Each permutation with `szvec` entries will have `szvec-1` indices pairwise adjacent. I am not sure about the lack of full connectivity. It is also unclear to me at this stage whether the graph will be a tree / collection of trees or if it would allow cycles.

Comment: "consider 24 choose 2 pairs of permutations" is O((n!)^2). "swap adjacent pairs" is O(n!*n).